# Expect: invalid command name "*"

Tags: expect

In my Expect script this line is throwing an error:

```
expect "Address or name of remote host [*]? "
```

In the log I see this error:

```
switchnumber1#invalid command name "*"
    while executing
"*"
    invoked from within
"expect "Address or name of remote host [*]? ""
```

The remote host ip address in the brackets could change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect uses Tcl. In Tcl, `[...]` in double quotes is the [command substitution](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11) syntax which is like `$(...)` (or `` `...` ``) in Bash.

To include a literal `[` char you could write:

```
expect "Address or name of remote host \[*]? "
```

Comment: Or, use Tcl's equivalent of the shell's single quotes: `expect {Address or name of remote host [*]? }`