# Can't run an expect script: invalid command name "Yes/No"

Tags: expect

I have this expect script that need to execute some other shell script to accept a Licence agreement

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./xxx.sh
expect -ex "--More--"
send -- " "
expect "Do you agree with this license ?[Yes/No]"
send "Y\r"
```

But when I run it I get this error

```
invalid command name "Yes/No"
while executing
"Yes/No"
invoked from within
"expect "Do you agree with this license ?[Yes/No]""
(file "./xxx.sh" line 5)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Presumably `[` `]` has a special meaning in double quotes in `expect`. Have you tried single quotes?

Comment: Yes, and I got the same error but in single quotes, lol
    `invalid command name "Yes/No" while executing "Yes/No" invoked from within "expect 'Do you agree with this license ?[Yes/No]'" (file "./run_forticlient.sh" line 5)`

Comment: Single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl/expect: they are just plain characters.

Comment: @glennjackman Hah. You beat me to it. I've just found http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expect: invalid command name "\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883910/expect-invalid-command-name)

Answer (score 4):

expect is an extension of the Tcl language. In Tcl, you use square brackets for [command substitution](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11). Like the bash shell, command substitution occurs within double quoted strings.

To prevent your code from attempting to execute the `Yes/No` command:

1. use different quotes: Tcl uses curly braces as the non-interpolating quotes:

   ```
   expect {Do you agree with this license ?[Yes/No]}
   ```
2. escape the brackets to prevent command substitution:

   ```
   expect "Do you agree with this license ?\[Yes/No\]"
   ```

Comment: I think option 1 works for me, option 2 give me error : `invalid command name "with"`.
Now it doesn't give me errors.